# How to get current server URL from service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to get URL address in application service level with SpringBoot? I need to save link to Entry in DB like:

```
var entity = new Entity();
   entity.setUrl(serverURL/API(with id));
```

The most tricky for me is how to get serverURL: it can be localhost, preprod.site.com or prod.site.com. I can ask controller for get request, but it looks awful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromCurrentRequest--) to obtain an `UriComponentsBuilder` based on the current `HttpServletRequest`:

```
int id = 4711;
String url = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/your/path/with/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(id)
                .toUriString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not query sensible "in context" information inside your business logic.**

Instead, add the request object as parameter for your method controller and inject as needed somewhere:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyBusinessLogic myBusinessLogic;

    @GetMapping("/my-path/..."})
    public String index(..., HttpServletRequest request) {

        String myURL = request.getRequestURI();

        myBusinessLogic.doTransaction(..., myURL, ...);
```

your code will be more robust, testeable, decoupled, reusable, ...

Comment: maybe I didn't describe full context.  Service is Kafka listener and I need do create link with id from DB, but before I need to save new entity